# Как переместить курсор мыши в конец текста

Tags: javascript, jasmine, enzyme

Как переместить курсор мыши в конец текста в тестах с enzyme,

```
textArea.simulate('change', {target: {
value: 'some text'
}});
textArea.simulate('mouseMove', {
pageX: 500,
pageY: 200,
type: 'mousemove'
});

console.log(textArea.node.selectionStart);

textArea.simulate('click');
textArea.simulate('keyUp', {keyCode: 32});
console.log(textArea.node.selectionStart);
```

пробовал даже так

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i = i + 10) {
textArea.simulate('mouseMove', {
    clientX: i,
    clientY: i,
    pageX: i,
    pageY: i,
    screenX: i,
    screenY: i
});
textArea.simulate('mouseDown')
textArea.simulate('mouseUp')

textArea.simulate('click');
console.log(textArea.node.selectionStart);// Все вермя выдает ноль
}
```

selectionStart  и в тесте и в методе который тестирую так же выдается по 0, а текст меняется нормально